# How to delcare the whole year SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure like this:

```
create proc SearchField (@YearDate)
```

How can I make this @YearDate to be as one whole year if I put only the Year? so if I put the '2013' it will search from 01-Jan-2013 up to 31-Dec-2013.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where year(your_date_column) = @year
```